# how to ensure a specific value is selected as default value in a drop downlist in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

What I'm trying to get is 'Another test' instead of 'test' as default value (selected when page loads) in dropdownlist.

In simple cases [as shown here](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/controlTypes.html) its easy.. but when you have nested structures as below.. what to do..

My html:

```
  <div data-bind="with:g">

            <div><input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: gname" /></div>

            <div>
                <table>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr data-bind="with:gdetails">
                            <td>
                                <select data-bind="options: eventschemas, optionsText: 'schema', value:eventschemacondition().schema, event: {change:eventschemacondition().setschema}"></select>

                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The js codebase:

```
 var eventschemas = [{ "schema": "Test" }, { "schema": "Another Test" }];

        var AppScope = function () {
            function EventSchemaCondition(data) {
                this.schema = ko.observable(data.schema);


            }

            function Gdetails(data) {
                this.eventschemacondition = ko.observable(data.eventschemacondition);
            }

            function G(data) {
                this.gname = ko.observable(data.gname);
                this.gdetails = ko.observable(data.gdetails);
            }

            function GsViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.g = ko.observable(
                new G({
                    gname: "",
                    gdetails: new Gdetails({ eventschemacondition: new EventSchemaCondition({ schema: "" }) })
                }));
            }

            ko.applyBindings(new GsViewModel());
        }();
```

[The full jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/22105/)

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple of minor changes to do as mentioned below

**View :** (Include `optionsValue`)

```
<select data-bind="options: eventschemas, optionsText: 'schema',optionsValue:'schema', value:schema, event: {change:setschema}"></select>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
 function EventSchemaCondition(data) { 
                this.schema = ko.observable("Another Test"); //set your default option
                this.setschema = function () {
                  //your code
                };
            }
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/23741/)**

Comment: tx, it does work but if I change the name of observable to something else, it does not --http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/23743/, any idea why this happens..

Comment: ok, got it.. 'optionsvalue' has same name as optionstext and 'value' has the value of observable http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/23744/

Comment: In my application $ data  is 
    "eventschemacondition": {
      "aschema": {
           "schema": ""
            }
    }
  due to which this.aschema = ko.observable("Another Test"); does not work, Unfortunately not able to reproduce the problem in a simple jsfiddle.. I tried this.aschema.schema="AnotherTest", did not work.. any ideas ??

Comment: all i can try is guessing around . did you try like this `this.aschema.schema("AnotherTest") ` as `schema` is observable .

Comment: guess is fine..but here, aschema is observable, schema comes from the data used in populating dropdownlist, tx..

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, all you want is for the drop to select 'Another test' which is item at index 1 in the `eventschemas` array that you declared as a global variable.

If you open the jsfiddle again and change the last `schema: ""` at the bottom of the script just before the applyBindings call to `schema: eventschemas[1]` it will select it in the drop-down.